# Three20 and TTTextEditor: howTo?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I want to add a simple `TTTextEditor` in my view from [Three20](http://three20.info).

I needed around 4 hours to get the freaking Three20 library working but now I'm ready, but haven't a single idea how to implement the `TTTextEditor`.

Any help?
Are there any HowTo's?